# iOS. I can´t play an mp3 calling a NSObject class, However it works directly from the UIViewController

Tags: ios

I can play an mp3 file with AVAudioPlayer framework directly in the ViewController as an action from a button, but if I want to play the same mp3 calling a selector in a NSObject Class, failed. Thanks for your advice.

Playing an mp3 from the ViewController (audioPlayerDemo.xcodeproj) and it works:

AVFoundation.framework included in the frameworks folder

APDViewController.h

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

    @interface APDViewController : UIViewController <AVAudioPlayerDelegate>
    {
    }
    @property (strong,nonatomic) AVAudioPlayer *audioPlay;

    - (IBAction)play:(id)sender;
```

APDViewController.m

```
    @implementation APDViewController

    @synthesize audioPlay;

    - (IBAction)play:(id)sender
    {
        NSError *error = nil;
        NSData *dataAudio = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:
           @"/Users/User/Documents/AudioPlayerDemo/AudioPlayerDemo/hello world.mp3"options:0 error:&error];
        if(error){
            NSLog(@" error loading data: %@ ", [error localizedDescription]);
        }
        else{
            audioPlay = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:dataAudio error:&error];
            if(error){
                NSLog(@" error loading audio: %@ ", [error localizedDescription]);
            }
            else{
                audioPlay.delegate = self;
                [audioPlay prepareToPlay];
                [audioPlay play];
            }
        } 
    }

    -(void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:
    (AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag
    {
        if (player == audioPlay){
            audioPlay = nil;
            NSLog(@"audioplay = nil");
        }
    }
```

But, if I want to play the same .mp3 calling a NSObject class (AudioPlayClass.xcodeproj), there is no error, neither any sound. Here the code that doesn`t work:

AVFoundation.framework included in the frameworks folder

APCplayObject.h

```
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
    #import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

    @interface APCplayObject : NSObject <AVAudioPlayerDelegate>
    {
    }
    @property (strong,nonatomic) AVAudioPlayer *audioPlay;

    - (void)playAudio;

    @end
```

APCplayObject.m

```
    #import "APCplayObject.h"
    @implementation APCplayObject

    @synthesize audioPlay;

    -(void)playAudio{

        NSError *error = nil;
        NSData *dataAudio = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:
           @"/Users/User/Documents/AudioPlayerClass/AudioPlayerClass/hello world.mp3"options:0 error:&error];
        if(error){
            NSLog(@" error loading data: %@ ", [error localizedDescription]);
        }
        else{
            audioPlay = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:dataAudio error:&error];
            if(error){
                NSLog(@" error loading audio: %@ ", [error localizedDescription]);
            }
            else{
                audioPlay.delegate = self;
                [audioPlay prepareToPlay];
                [audioPlay play];
            }
        }
    }

    -(void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:
    (AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag  
    {
        if (player == audioPlay){
            audioPlay = nil;
            NSLog(@"audioplay = nil");
        }
    }
```

APCviewController.m, the caller as an action from a button:

```
    - (IBAction)callPlay:(id)sender {
        APCplayObject *a = [[APCplayObject alloc] init];
        [a playAudio];

    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that after you start the audio playing, the variable `a` goes out of scope and is therefore destroyed.

You need to create a declared property to hold your `APCplayObject` when the method exits.

So, in `APCviewController.h` you can do something like this:

```
@property (strong,nonatomic) APCplayObject *playObject;
```

And then change callPlay to:

```
- (IBAction)callPlay:(id)sender {
    if (!self.playObject)  // Use this line if you only want to create one playObject, take it out to create a new one every time.
        self.playObject = [[APCplayObject alloc] init];
    [self.playObject playAudio];

}
```

Comment: He's using ARC. If he weren't, he wouldn't have noticed his bug as the audio player wouldn't be destroyed on going out of scope as things stand and the "is therefore" wouldn't apply. It used to be you could clumsily autorelease the audio player and pray it lived long enough!

Comment: Exactly. The OP is using ARC, if he weren't he wouldn't have noticed this issue. It's because he's using ARC that your "is therefore" applies.

Comment: In other words, this post should be noted "Assuming you are using ARC, ..." so that boneheads don't take this answer and run with it without using ARC (that's becoming more and more rare these days, but I am still surprised at the amount of times I spot it)

Comment: Well, I never even considered that this might be non-ARC since one of the first lines of his code is `@property (strong,...`.  Thanks for pointing it out for those that it might not be so obvious for though.

Comment: The assumption is correct, I´m using ARC. Thanks for the comments SK9 and borrrden

Comment: Great, welcome to SO!  Since this answers your question, please select the checkmark at the top left of the question to make it as a correct answer.  Glad I could help!

Comment: Yes, thank you, I was just wondering why it's not playing as well and this is exactly the reason!